# Moodle Installation Error-- "version 5.4.4 is required and you are running 7.1.10.1.17.10.1.1"

Tags: ubuntu, web, webserver, web-hosting, moodle

When installing moodle on my ubuntu server I have the error "version 5.4.4 is required and you are running 7.1.10.1.17.10.1.1" and "PHP version 7.1 is not supported." how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are installing an older version of Moodle - latest version (Moodle 3.3.2+, at the time of writing) fully supports PHP 7.1.

Download an up-to-date version of Moodle here: https://download.moodle.org/